# split xml file depending on record count in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have temp.xml file with below contents,

```
   <records>
      <profile/>
      <profile/>
      <profile/>
      <profile/>
      .
      .
    </records>
```

I will pass the number of records,'n', as the input. I want the temp.xml file to be split into 'n' number of records. For eg., if I have 4 records in temp.xml and if I pass n value as 2, then 2 files has to be created with 2 records each.

The output file name can be anything. For eg., below is the sample output. where 4 records are split into 2 files with 2 records (profile). Records count should be consistent.

```
temp1.xml
<profile/>
<profile/>

temp2.xml
<profile/>
<profile/>
```

Comment: What if total record count in file is not divisible by n?

Comment: use awk, set `RS='<profile'` & based on n passed & NR value, change the output file name.

Comment: last file should contain remaining recods, for eg: temp.xml will have 13 records and split size is 2 then 6 file with 2 records and 7th file will contain 1 record.

Answer (score 2):

i have splited the file using below command

```
split -l 3 -a 2 temp.xml remp.xml_
```

-a 2 :will be used to create file name like temp.xml_aa, temp.xml_ab